# How do I copy icon designs from Photoshop to Illustrator in order to turn them into .svg?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon, svg

I'm a newbie in creating font icons from .svg. I created some icons in Photoshop (.psd), and now I want to copy all of them to Illustrator to create an .svg file but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi The Hung, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: No problem! I [edit]ed your question to better reflect what I think you are asking. If I'm wrong, don't hesitate to [edit] things back!

Answer (score 2):

If they're created as shapes in Photoshop using the pen tool you should just be able to copy paste them into Illustrator.

I've created my own fonts the same way in Illustrator using [fontastic.me](http://fontastic.me)

Just create a new illustrator doc and paste each character into a new layer. Save each character as an .svg and then import them all into Fontastic. Sometimes fontastic can crash when doing multiple icons so if this happens you might have to import them individually.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank @neil-hanvey for replying, I don't know extacly how it created because I buy from Themeforest. In addition, can you show me how to use pen tool to copy it because it'll create a path instead of copying.

Answer (score 1):

You can also export the file to Illustrator paths if you have a lot of shapes to convert by going <kbd>File > Export > Paths to Illustrator</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, I did but after converted to path in Photoshop, it doesn't smooth.

Comment: Hi Jigz, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

You can also export SVGs directly from Photoshop using [PNG Express](http://pngexpress.com). It works on both CS5, CS6, CC, and CC2014. It generates 100% non-rasterized SVGs which is not the case with the built-in PS CC tool. In my opinion it exports the most accurate SVGs, but I'm the developer so I might be biased.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually export them directly to SVG through Photoshop itself through 'Extract Assets' dialog. Just select each layer or group that would be an SVG and right click on them to click on 'Extract Assets…'. This only works in the latest Photoshop CC release though (*and I work on this dialog at Adobe*). Would that help?